# InfoPath Library form missing attachments

Tags: infopath, attachments, form-library

I have created a library form with a repeating table and with an attachment field (for multiple attachments) and using Send an Email (Data connection on form), submitted it to Outlook. I received an email on Outlook with a blank field for attachment field section. Hence I was unable to view the file names on attachment field on Outlook email. Can you please let me know the ways of displaying the attachments/attachment titles over Outlook email for a library form.

Answer (score 0):

You can't receive the attachments on email. Because in `info-path` forms all the `InfoPath` attachments are stored as pieces of text called **`base64`** encoded strings within the InfoPath form itself.. So you cant attach the documents to the email. 
[image]
You can also use a custom `SharePoint Designer` action to extract `InfoPath` file attachments and then upload them to SharePoint either as attachments in a SharePoint List or documents in a SharePoint Document Library.

Please refer the [Link](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/04/top-10-questions-infopath-file-attachments/)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. I just want to show the attachment file names on the Outlook email instead of displaying blank fields for attachments row.

Comment: Please refer the link for create the workflow to get the file names